# JMX MBean to manage dynamic set of properties

Tags: java, jboss, dictionary, jmx

The problem might sound similar to many resolved ones, but I did not shoot this target yet.

I am about to create a MBean that will allow me to specify dynamic set of key-value pairs.

(It is easy to create a solution to specify pre-defined set of params. But what about dynamic ones)

The most relevant code snippets i could find was usage of `CompositeData`, TabularData

The api is next:

```
applyNewProperties(Properties props)
```

UI is next:

mbean method `applyNewProperties`

Parameters: props

```
name1  value1
name2  value2
name3  value3
.....
namen value n
```

The purpose is that jmx-connsole would show it in table form:

```
input name 1 input value 1
input name 2 input value 2
input name 3 input value 3
....
input name n input value n
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/modelmbean/ModelMBeanInfo.html

Comment: ModelIMBeanInfo might help, working on it

Comment: No, CompositeData seems like more correct approach:)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would probably be to create an [MXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html) (which is available since Java 6) which allows you to return objects like maps (or completely custom objects) which are then mapped into *Open Types* like CompositeData or TabularData instances.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not true. Your MXBean cannot return a `java.util.Map`, it must be translated into either a `CompositeData` or `TabularData` type.

Comment: @nilskp The MXBean may very well return a `Map`, which will then be mapped to a `TabularData` instance. See the section _Type mapping rules_ [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 brought us DynamicMBean - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html

I believe that's what you want.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that DynamicMBeans are dynamic from a compile time perspective, but not from a continuous runtime perspective. When the bean is registered, the properties become static, i.e. you cannot add and remove properties without unregistering/re-registering.